# Issues adding a new directory inside of intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, directory, minecraft, minecraft-forge

This is what I currently see:
[image: what i currently see]

When I add a new directory to my assets folder this happens:
[image]

I don't know if it's adding properly but for some reason I don't see it displaying under the `assets` folder like it's supposed to.

One thing that I tried that somewhat worked was adding a temporary file under the directory, and it worked until I deleted that file. After that point it went back to normal.

Comment: Likely just IntelliJ flattening the directories into their package representations. It's just a visual thing; you still have two directories, one nested under the other.

Answer (score 1):

In the Project Tool Window click the cogwheel icon -> Tree Appearance, adjust "Flatten Packages" and "Compact Middle Packages / Hide Empty Middle Packages" options.

If you prefer Project Tool Window to match the file system structure exactly you can also switch from "Project" to "Project Files" view in the top left corner of the Project Tool Window.
[image: Screenshot]